# Android - WIFI Configuration OTA using URL

Tags: android, configuration, wifi, provisioning, ota

I need to deploy OTA WIFI configuration on Android devices.
For example, by deploying an XML file on a Web server accessible by an URL from the mobile. Do you have any idea on how to proceed?

On iOS devices, we just need a configuration provisionning deployed on a server to configure mail, Wifi, certificate, and many others things.

The Android Device Administration API introduced with Android 2.2 doesn't include WIFI management API/feature.

Comment: do these devices have connection to the internet before your wifi configuration takes place? if not that is going to make it rather difficult for them to hit a server.

Comment: Yes, the device have an Internet connection for installing Wifi configuration

Comment: Are you able to get some application running on the devices in order to help you handle this? Or does it have to be using only one comes loaded on the device out of the box?

Comment: The user already uses his Android device for every day operations. He have an 3G or Wifi access. We don't want to provide an app for configuring Wifi, just an web server URL for OTA deployment.

Comment: AFAIK there are no web technologies that allow you manipulate the Network Manager API to get it to join a specific network. The closest thing I can think of is using Barcode Scanner on the devices and handing out barcodes with the network info embedded in them. [If you go to this page](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) and choose  'wifi network' in the dropdown it will allow you to create a code that when scanned will prompt the user to join the specified network. It is not using any web protocol to achieve that though I think it's just feature of the Barcode Scanner app that allows it.

Comment: This can't be a solution for me because I have to configure a WIFI network connection secured by user certificate. I think there is no way to do that by OTA :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are third party commercial solutions (search for Clearpass from Aruba or JoinNow from Securew2), but nothing (as for Android 4.2) like the deployment API in the iOS world.